# Find 2 values of $\theta$ such that $0 \leq\theta \lt 2\pi$ and $9 \sin \theta + 6 \cos \theta = 0.$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not really sure where to head from this question besides rearranging the equation and simplifying it to $3\sin\theta+2\cos\theta=0$ or $\tan\theta=-6/9.$

From here I'm unsure how to find values of $\theta$ within the given range.

Comment: Hint: You can write your answers as $\theta = \arctan(...)+k$ where $...$ and $k$ are appropriate expressions.

Comment: @Dylan Parr When you divide the equation by $\cos\theta$ to get $\tan\theta=-6/9$, in fact you assumed $\cos\theta\neq0$. So you should consider the case $\cos\theta=0$ separately too. (Although in this equation $\cos\theta=0\Rightarrow \theta=k\pi+\frac{\pi}2$ is not a solution).

Comment: As other responses have indicated, if you examine the arctan function, you will notice that it's domain is all of $\Bbb{R}$, its range is $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2$, and it is a continuous, strictly increasing function.  Clearly, there must be exactly one satisfying value of $\theta$ in the 4th quadrant [where $\sin(\theta) < 0, \cos(\theta) > 0$].  So, the trick is to realize that there will be exactly one *counterpart* angle in the 2nd quadrant [where $\sin(\theta) > 0, \cos(\theta) < 0].$

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bvsoblbwsz

Answer (score 1):

Well, you’ve basically solved it already. Any $\theta$ that solves the original problem has to solve $\tan\theta = -2/3$. So considering that the $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic you can get the solution by taking the arctan of $-2/3$ and adding an integral multiple of $\pi$. Also you can easily revert your simplification to prove that any such solution is also a solution of the original problem.

So do this and filter out all solutions that fall in your range.

Comment: @Dylan Parr , continuing on this answer and the comments above, I recommend having look (or learning) about the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle), specifically which quadrants will certain circular functions result in a negative value (of the angles in that quadrant).